# Cloudflare in cPanel is it a no brainer?

Tags: cpanel, cdn, cloudflare

I recently noticed a CloudFlare CDN service addon appear in my cPanel. I understand what a CDN is, but thought it was a more complicated process than the one-click solution that seems to be offered in cPanel now.

Can anyone vouch for this service through cPanel and if it is indeed easy to set up as it looks. Do I risk breaking anything on a dynamic site?

Comment: There is also a similar question here: [Should I enable CloudFlare through cPanel, or set it up directly via cloudflare.com?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86863/should-i-enable-cloudflare-through-cpanel-or-set-it-up-directly-via-cloudflare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare activation is ridiculously simple. If you want to use it, I'm not sure that using it through cpanel is the way to go. You can sign up directly from their site, and they have a free package you can start with. If you don't like it, you can always deactivate and content will go back to being served directly from your server.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare works, but my load times are always higher under it, except on opposite sides of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare should be clever enough to spot static files and dynamic files. It does appear to be that simple: https://www.cloudflare.com/overview

It looks like what's happening when you enable that in cPanel is that you're enabling mod_cloudflare.

Comment: It's not *just* about mod_cloudflare Paul. mod_cloudflare is only a very minor part of the CloudFlare service for enhancing compatibility with existing apps.  The major benefit is routing all traffic through their CDN network.